# HAMRS logging app dumped all data

Tags: logging

Anyone have this issue. HAMRS logging app on Android dumped 3 months of logs. It's an amateur radio logging app where you log your contacts. I went to open the app the other day and my profile and all of my logged contacts for the last 3 months are all gone. It is as if I had just downloaded the app and set it up for the first time. I wondered is that data somewhere stored in a hidden folder or something on my phone where I would be able to access it somehow. If not I'll have to start all over and lose all those contacts. I have emailed the dev. Awaiting a response.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and explain what "dumped 3 months of logs" means? Because "logs" means something different to Android developers than it does radio people. In general, try to add as much detail as you can about what you were doing, what you tried, and what results you got. Welcome to HAM.SE. Make sure you take the [tour] if you have not done so already.

Comment: Well sorry. Thought I wrote that. HAMRS app. It's an amateur radio logging app where you log your contacts. I went to open the app the other day and my profile and all of my logged contacts for the last 3 months are all gone. It is as if I had just downloaded the app and set it up for the first time. I wondered is that data somewhere stored in a hidden folder or something on my phone where I would be able to access it somehow. If not I'll have to start all over and lose all those contacts. I have emailed the dev. Awaiting a response.

Comment: Even though it is specific to ham-related software, the ways to get access to the protected areas where Android apps store data would be best researched on an Android related SE. There isn't anything specific to contact logging software that would make this any different than any other Android app. You are either looking for ADB access, or you may luck out and a File Explorer app might show you that the data is in a more shared location. Best you work directly with the application author, and if you are stuck, ask Android experts for techniques for extracting data from devices.

Comment: Thank you. I will seek out more help.